# Java - Vertical Histogram troubleshoot: broken max value?

Tags: java, histogram, vertical-alignment

So after much trial and error I converted my horizontal histogram to a vertical one, at least partially.

It seems that instead of reading the highest number of times used, it simply reads the value of the highest-used number:

```
How many input values [max:30]?
5
Enter 5 numbers.
2
1
2
0
2
Number Occurrence
0 1
1 1
2 3

========= Vertical Bar ========
2    |     * 
1    | * * * 
===============================
| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
===============================
```

leaves out the max height of 3 and removes an asterisk

```
How many input values [max:30]?
1
Enter 1 numbers.
5
Number Occurrence
5 1

========= Vertical Bar ========
5    |   
===============================
| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
===============================
```

does not print

```
5
Enter 5 numbers.
3
3
3
3
3
Number Occurrence
3 5

========= Vertical Bar ========
3    | * 
===============================
| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
===============================
```

prints the wrong max, the wrong number of asterisks, and in the wrong spot

```
How many input values [max:30]?
10
Enter 10 numbers.
5
4
3
2
1
1
2
3
4
5
Number Occurrence
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 2
5 2

========= Vertical Bar ========
5    |           
4    |           
3    |           
2    | * * * * * 
1    | * * * * * 
===============================
| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
===============================
```

adds whitespace for 5-3

```
10
Enter 10 numbers.
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
1
Number Occurrence
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4

========= Vertical Bar ========
4    |       * 
3    |     * * 
2    |   * * * 
1    | * * * * 
===============================
| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
===============================
```

works as intended although not by design

```
public class Histogram
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //variables
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numInputs = 1, temp, maximum = 0;
        int[] numbers = new int[31];
        int[] count = new int[31];
        boolean success = false;

        //start of program
        System.out.println("How many input values [max:30]?");

        //while no valid input
        while (!success) {
            try {
                numInputs = keyboard.nextInt(); //get a number
                numInputChecker(numInputs);     //is it valid?
                success = true;                 //ok

            } catch (Exception e)                 //else get a new number
            {
                keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Whole numbers 1 through 30 only, please.");

            }
        }
        //reset the loop checker
        success = false;

        //read numbers to fill that array
        System.out.println("Enter " + numInputs + " numbers.");

        for (int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)     //from 0 to max number
        {
            while (!success)                   //while no valid number
            {
                try {
                    numbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();    //fill the current cell with a number
                    numberChecker(numbers[i]);          //is it valid?
                    success = true;                     //ok
                } catch (Exception e)                     //else get a new number
                {
                    keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Whole numbers 0 through 9 only, please.");
                }
            }
            success = false;
        }

        //for cells not used
        for (int i = numInputs; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = 10;    //fill with garbage data (to prevent false positive 0s)
        }

        //take the input and count each use of element
        for (int i : numbers)  //for 0 to max number
        {
            temp = i;  //get the current value of the cell
            count[temp]++;      //add the use of that value to a new array's cell
        }

        System.out.println("Number Occurrence");

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)   //from 0 to 9 (expected)
        {
            if ((count[i] > 0) && (count[i] <= 9))  //if cell not empty and has valid data
            {
                System.out.println(i + " " + count[i]);  //print the current cell and how many times it was used
            }
        }
        System.out.println();   //spacer

        //histogram segment

        //find the highest-used number
        for (int i : count)             //for each number
        {
            if(i > maximum)             //if greater than the current max
            {
                maximum = i;            //set to max
            }
        }

        System.out.println("========= Vertical Bar ========");
        for (int i = maximum; i > 0; i--)        //max through 1
        {
            if ((count[i] > 0) && (count[i] <=9))   //if has valid data
            {
                System.out.print((i) + "\t | ");      // print the number and a nice line for readability

                for (int j = 0; j < count.length; j++)      //for the number of times that number was used
                {
                    if ((count[j] > 0) && (count[j] <=9))   //if has valid data
                    {
                        if (count[j] >= i)                  //if that number the max
                        {
                            System.out.print("* ");            //print an asterisk
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                System.out.print("  ");     //"skip" and keep alignment
                            }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();                   //make a new line
            }
        }

            System.out.println("===============================");  //footer
            System.out.println("| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
            System.out.println("===============================");
        }

    static void numInputChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 1) || (integer > 30))    //if 0 or negative, or if 31+
        {
            throw new Exception();              //say no
        }
    }

    static void numberChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 0) || (integer > 9)) //if negative or 10+
        {
            throw new Exception();          //say no
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have too many `if` blocks in your asterisks output logic.  You're deciding not to print anything at some horizontal positions based on the data, when what you really want to do is print two characters (either a space plus an asterisk or two spaces) at each position horizontally, regardless of if you saw any numbers at that position.  So your print code gets simpler and does the right thing if you take out all but one `if` block to arrive at this:

```
System.out.println("========= Vertical Bar ========");
// for each count, starting from the max...
for (int i = maximum; i > 0; i--) 
{
    System.out.print((i) + "\t | ");          

    // for each number from 0 to the largest number we saw
    for (int j = 0; j < count.length; j++) 
    {
        // If the count at this position horizontally is greater than or
        // equal to the count vertically (the line number we're on), then
        // print an asterisk, else print a blank space.
        if (count[j] >= i).   
        {                    
            System.out.print("* ");           
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("  ");           
        }
    }
    System.out.println();                  
}

System.out.println("===============================");
System.out.println("| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
System.out.println("===============================");
```

Here's a pretty complicated result that I was using for testing:

Input:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7 };
```

Result:

```
Number Occurrence
1 3
2 1
3 5
4 1
5 5
7 1

========= Vertical Bar ========
5    |       *   *                                                   
4    |       *   *                                                   
3    |   *   *   *                                                   
2    |   *   *   *                                                   
1    |   * * * * *   *                                               
===============================
| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
===============================
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect, thank you! The way I have it set up, I need that extra if statement to check for garbage data in the array, otherwise it gives me fake 10s, but I can fix that.

Comment: Oh yeah.  I was using a smaller `numbers[]` with just the right number of items in it for testing.  Just use the `numInputs ` value you have to only go that far through the `numbers[]` array to build up the `count[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Histogram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //variables
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numInputs = 1, temp, maximum = 0;
        int[] numbers = new int[31];
        int[] count = new int[31];
        boolean success = false;

        //start of program
        System.out.println("How many input values [max:30]?");

        //while no valid input
        while (!success)
        {
            try
            {
                numInputs = keyboard.nextInt(); //get a number
                numInputChecker(numInputs);     //is it valid?
                success = true;                 //ok

            } catch (Exception e)                 //else get a new number
            {
                keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Whole numbers 1 through 30 only, please.");

            }
        }
        //reset the loop checker
        success = false;

        //read numbers to fill that array
        System.out.println("Enter " + numInputs + " numbers.");

        for (int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)     //from 0 to max number
        {
            while (!success)                   //while no valid number
            {
                try
                {
                    numbers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();    //fill the current cell with a number
                    numberChecker(numbers[i]);          //is it valid?
                    success = true;                     //ok
                } catch (Exception e)                   //else get a new number
                {
                    keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Whole numbers 0 through 9 only, please.");
                }
            }
            success = false;
        }

        //for cells not used
        for (int i = numInputs; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = -1;    //fill with garbage data (to prevent false positive 0s)
        }

        //take the input and count each use of element
        for (int i : numbers)  //for 0 to max number
        {
            if (i != -1)       //if valid data
            {
                temp = i;           //get the current value of the cell
                count[temp]++;      //add the use of that value to a new array's cell
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Number Occurrence");

        for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)   //from 0 to 9 (expected)
        {
            if (count[i] > 0)  //if cell has valid data
            {
                System.out.println(i + " " + count[i]);  //print the current cell and how many times it was used
            }
        }
        System.out.println();   //spacer

        //histogram segment

        //find the highest-used number
        for (int k : count)              //for 0 to 9
        {
            if (k > maximum)             //if greater than the current max
            {
                maximum = k;             //set to max
            }
        }

        System.out.println("========= Vertical Bar ========");

        for (int i = maximum; i > 0; i--) // from max to 1
        {
            System.out.print((i) + "\t | ");    //print the number and a spacer for visibility


            for (int j = 0; j < count.length; j++)   // from 0 to max
            {

                    if (count[j] >= i)                    // If the count at this position horizontally is greater than or
                                                          // equal to the count vertically (the line number we're on)
                    {
                        System.out.print("* ");           //print an asterisk
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            System.out.print("  ");       //else print a blank
                        }
            }
            System.out.println();                         //spacer
        }
        //footer
        System.out.println("===============================");
        System.out.println("| No | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
        System.out.println("===============================");
        }

    static void numInputChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 1) || (integer > 30))    //if 0 or negative, or if 31+
        {
            throw new Exception();              //say no
        }
    }

    static void numberChecker(int integer) throws Exception
    {
        if ((integer < 0) || (integer > 9)) //if negative or 10+
        {
            throw new Exception();          //say no
        }
    }

}
```